# Problems with Drupal 7.55 Apache2 Subdomain Virtual Host no CSS

Tags: 7

Setting up a fresh Drupal install in the domain root example.com works fine.
Removing that and using a copy of the default virtualhost config file for a new virtual host site.example.com with a ServerName site.example.com and a different DocumentRoot, I navigate to site.example.com and css is not applied, I just get the install.php but without css.

All clean install on Debian Jessie - should be easy to replicate.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: First of all, don't do a fresh install with an outdated version of Drupal (with known security issues) - please use the latest version 7.60. Anyway, the easiest way to solve/understand this issue is to look at the webserver access log. You probably have 404/not found for the CSS files. Update you question with this info and we can tell if it is a clean URL issue or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and fix this things:

1. File system (admin/config/media/file-system) and setup it on the proper way.
2. Clear all cache
3. add proper permission for apache2 user (chown -R www-data:www-data sitename.com)
4. check settings.php - database name, database user and cookies domain
5. check recent log files and try to find messages for the content with access denied permissions

This is for Drupal 7, also similar, can used for Drupal 8

Thanks, Vladica